# Need to convert the double data type precision of scale 1 to 2 in informatica cloud expression transformation

Tags: double, expression, decimal, informatica, informatica-cloud

My incoming  field -->double datattype (veeva)--> for eg.s, 134.0 , 45.4,61.234
My output needs to be always 2 places of decimal --->file ---> field value: 134.00, 45.40, 61.23

I have tried creating an expression on informatica cloud:
`TO_DECIMAL( IN_TAX, 2 )`
but its not giving the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the data type to double with decimal point =2 and use `round()`. I am assuming your target is a flat file.
create an out port in exp transformation like below -

```
out_tax = ROUND(in_tax,2)  -- data type is DOUBLE(xx,2), where xx is your precision.
```

Link this port to target.

Comment: Thanks , I edited the scale to 2 of output field in Expression and it worked. :)

Comment: i am glad that the solution worked... :)